# Get deployments counts on Ansible Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

How to get deployment counts on Ansible Tower? Is there any way to get deployment counts using ansible tower REST API?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by deployment count?

Comment: I mean last couple-off Jobs history list which was ran by user from some date to date and here don't want to mention any particular jobs, it should be date range or last jobs history list

Comment: you can write a playbook to extract the data you need from tower API, but it may not be that easy to do so.I would rather prefer to get that data from tower database.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Could you please guide me how to get that data from tower database. Please provide me some examples

Answer (score 0):

In respect of your question and comment

> *... or last jobs history list ...*

you could use according the [Ansible Tower REST API](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html) and [Jobs - List jobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Jobs/Jobs_jobs_list) something like

```bash
curl --silent -u "${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/jobs/ | jq .
```

which provides also a Sorting and Searching option, in example `?order_by=name`.